# pyplot - negative numbers are not displayed correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I change the default font to "Times New Roman", the negative numbers are not displayed correctly. I was wondering what the problem is and how I can solve it. I am using either `plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Times New Roman"` or `plt.rc('font',family='Times New Roman')`. Here are the pictures for default font and new font, respectively.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like matplotlib is not using *minus signs*, but *dashes*s (or something similar).

Comment: What is `plt.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus']`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, it worked! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @WillemVanOnsem mentioned in the comment below original question, it can be solved by using `plt.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False`